# Should I use HttpURLConnection or RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

Should I use `HttpURLConnection` in a `Spring` Project Or better to use `RestTemplate` ?
In other words, When it is better to use each ?

Answer (score 25):

The [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) are different kind of beasts. They operate on different abstraction levels.

The `RestTemplate` helps to consume [`REST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) api and the `HttpURLConnection` works with HTTP protocol.

You're asking what is better to use. The answer depends on what you're trying to achieve:

- If you need to consume `REST` api then stick with `RestTemplate`
- If you need to work with http protocol then use <strike>`HttpURLConnection`</strike>, `OkHttpClient`, Apache's `HttpClient`, or if you're using Java 11 you can try its `HttpClient`.

Moreover the `RestTemplate` uses `HttpUrlConnection`/`OkHttpClient`/... to do its work (see [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html), [`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html), [`OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory.html)

---

### Why you should not use `HttpURLConnection`?

It's better to show some code:

In  examples below [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) used

Let's `GET` a post:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  URL url;
  try {
    url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // Deal with it.
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;
  try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
      // Wrap, wrap, wrap

      StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
      }
      // Here is the response body
      System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } finally {
    if (connection != null) {
      connection.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

Now let's `POST` a post something:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
     OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
     BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(osw)) {
  wr.write("{\"title\":\"foo\", \"body\": \"bar\", \"userId\": 1}");
}
```

If the response needed:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
  // Wrap, wrap, wrap

  StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
  }

  System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

As you can see the api provided by the `HttpURLConnection` is ascetic.

You always have to deal with "low-level" `InputStream`, `Reader`, `OutputStream`, `Writer`, but fortunately there are alternatives.

---

#### The [`OkHttpClient`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

The `OkHttpClient` reduces the pain:

`GET`ting a post:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    .build();
Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
try (Response response = call.execute();
     ResponseBody body = response.body()) {

  String string = body.string();
  System.out.println(string);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

`POST`ing a post:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8"),
        "{\"title\":\"foo\", \"body\": \"bar\", \"userId\": 1}"))
    .url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .build();

Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);

try (Response response = call.execute();
     ResponseBody body = response.body()) {

  String string = body.string();
  System.out.println(string);
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Much easier, right?

#### Java 11's [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)

`GET`ting the posts:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"))
    .GET()
    .build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.body());
```

`POST`ing a post:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    .uri(URI.create("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"))
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{\"title\":\"foo\", \"body\": \"barzz\", \"userId\": 2}"))
    .build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

---

### The [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

According to its javadoc:

> Synchronous client to perform HTTP requests, exposing a simple, template method API over underlying HTTP client libraries such as the JDK {@code HttpURLConnection}, Apache HttpComponents, and others.

Lets do the same

Firstly for convenience the `Post` class is created. (When the `RestTemplate` will read the response it will transform it to a `Post` using [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html))

```
public static class Post {
  public long userId;
  public long id;
  public String title;
  public String body;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this)
        .toString();
  }
}
```

`GET`ting a post.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Post> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", Post.class);
Post post = entity.getBody();
System.out.println(post);
```

`POST`ing a post:

```
public static class PostRequest {
  public String body;
  public String title;
  public long userId;
}

public static class CreatedPost {
  public String body;
  public String title;
  public long userId;
  public long id;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this)
        .toString();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  PostRequest postRequest = new PostRequest();
  postRequest.body = "bar";
  postRequest.title = "foo";
  postRequest.userId = 11;


  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  CreatedPost createdPost = restTemplate.postForObject("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/", postRequest, CreatedPost.class);
  System.out.println(createdPost);
}
```

---

So to answer your question:

> When it is better to use each ?

- Need to consume `REST` api? Use `RestTemplate`
- Need to work with http? Use some `HttpClient`.

---

Also worth mentioning:

- [`Retrofit`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Intro to `Feign`](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-feign)
- [Declarative REST client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html)